# ReSharper Intellisense for ALL_UPPER constants

Tags: c#, resharper

If I have a constant with name *SomeConst* (in UpperCamelCase form) in my code I can enter just the upper letters *SC* for showing it in intellisense list.
Is there a similar behaviour for constants in ALL_UPPER format, i.e. `SOME_CONST`?
I tried also *SC*. But `SOME_CONST` did not appear in intellisense proposal list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. The re-sharper 'Go to' functionality only supports Camel Case naming conventions http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html

Answer (score 1):

I can do this in resharper 6.1.1000.82 I could not do it before this version.

Currently if I have a const like this

```
public const string TEST_ME = "Hello";
```

and I type TM after hitting ctrl-space then my constant appears for selection. You can also generate constants in this style by editing the code formatting options in resharpers option dialogs under languages.

After another quick check there is no need to hit ctrl-space thats just my habits.

[image: Example]

Comment: Interestingly this appears to be the exception to the rule, just tell me if you can see it work with TEST_ME I suspect it works because the start of the variable is TEST. Tested on two other machines also.

Comment: *`TEST_ME`* and *`TEST_CONST`* works on my machine. *`TES_CONST`* does not work on my machine. It seems it works only with members starting with *`TEST`*.

Comment: Might pop over to jetbrains and file a bug and see what occurs